Error When Deploying Custom ERC777 Token: Transaction Reverted
I'm trying to deploy a custom ERC777 token using Hardhat and ethers.js version 6. However, I keep getting an error related to a "function call to a non-contract account". I've been struggling with this for a couple of days, and I've tried different variations, but nothing seems to work.
Here is the token contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/ERC777.sol";

contract SimpleERC777Token is ERC777 {
    constructor() ERC777("EP777", "EP7", new address ) {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000 * 10**18, "", "");
    }
}

The deployment script being:
import { ethers } from "ethers";

async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

    console.log("Deploying SimpleERC777Token with the deployer:", deployer.address);

    // Get the contract factory
    const ERC777TokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleERC777Token");

    // Deploy the contract
    const erc777Token = await ERC777TokenFactory.deploy();

    await erc777Token.waitForDeployment();

    console.log("SimpleERC777Token deployed at:", await erc777Token.getAddress());
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});

Error: Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account

In your SimpleERC777Token constructor, you are passing new address as the third parameter. However, it should be an array of addresses. If you don't want to specify any operators, you can simply pass an empty array [].
Additionally, in your script, you should use await erc777Token.deployed(); instead of await erc777Token.waitForDeployment();, as the latter is not a valid method in the ethers.js library.

I think to get the deployed address you have to do:
    console.log("SimpleERC777Token deployed at:", erc777Token.target);

The other parts look correct.
